# Removing localization in liferay theme

Tags: localization, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am using Liferay 6.1 and have developed theme in the same. My problem is when i load the theme the head section contains huge links as shown below:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ar-SA" href="http://localhost/ar">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="eu-ES" href="http://localhost/eu">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="bg-BG" href="http://localhost/bg">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ca-AD" href="http://localhost/ca">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ca-ES" href="http://localhost/ca_ES">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-CN" href="http://localhost/zh">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-TW" href="http://localhost/zh_TW">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="hr-HR" href="http://localhost/hr">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="cs-CZ" href="http://localhost/cs">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="da-DK" href="http://localhost/da">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" href="http://localhost/nl">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="http://localhost/nl_BE">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://localhost/en_GB">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="et-EE" href="http://localhost/et">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fi-FI" href="http://localhost/fi">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-FR" href="http://localhost/fr">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="gl-ES" href="http://localhost/gl">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="http://localhost/de">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="el-GR" href="http://localhost/el">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="iw-IL" href="http://localhost/iw">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="hi-IN" href="http://localhost/hi">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="hu-HU" href="http://localhost/hu">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="in-ID" href="http://localhost/in">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="it-IT" href="http://localhost/it">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja-JP" href="http://localhost/ja">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko-KR" href="http://localhost/ko">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="lo-LA" href="http://localhost/lo">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nb-NO" href="http://localhost/nb">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fa-IR" href="http://localhost/fa">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl-PL" href="http://localhost/pl">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt-BR" href="http://localhost/pt">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt-PT" href="http://localhost/pt_PT">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ro-RO" href="http://localhost/ro">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-RU" href="http://localhost/ru">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sr-RS" href="http://localhost/sr">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sr-RS-latin" href="http://localhost/sr_RS_latin">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sl-SI" href="http://localhost/sl">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sk-SK" href="http://localhost/sk">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ES" href="http://localhost/es">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sv-SE" href="http://localhost/sv">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr-TR" href="http://localhost/tr">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="uk-UA" href="http://localhost/uk">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="vi-VN" href="http://localhost/vi">
```

I want remove languages that are not needed. I want these links to be removed as this is not the good practice for SEO. I want a default language for a theme. I tried adding `translations.disabled=true` in the portal-ext file but this didnt worked.

Your any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to restricted to the locales you want to use, adding the "locales" property to portal-ext.porperties. To restrict it to englisch and german for example, you can do this

> locales=en_US,de_DE

Comment: I have added the locales=en_US but still all the other links gets showed in the head tag.

Comment: And one more thing which can help you to guide me. Whenever i login to the admin the links doesnt gets showed. But when i deploy the theme it does show the links as shown above.

Comment: Thank you  :) Regarding the locales, it should work. You can try it on a fresh instance of Liferay. I think there is some other thing wrong in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

See also the [official wiki documentation](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Languagedisplay+customization#section-Languagedisplay+customization-Setting+a+default+Language+and+default+Country)

I quote it here:

> Removing unwanted language
>
> By default, Liferay supports all the follow languages (excerpt from portal.properties of Liferay 4.3.3):
>
> > locales=ar_SA,ca_AD,ca_ES,zh_CN,zh_TW,cs_CZ,nl_NL,en_US,fi_FI,fr_FR,de_DE,el_GR,hu_HU,it_IT,ja_JP,ko_KR,fa_IR,pt_BR,ru_RU,es_ES,sv_SE,tr_TR,vi_VN
>
> If we only want to support English, German and Spanish, we simply remove the unwanted locales so that our locales value looks like this:
>
> ```
> locales=en_US,de_DE,es_ES
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The portal-ext.properties settings can be overridden my Portal settings at `Control Panel > Settings > Display Settings > Available Languages`. I'd say it's safe to set them there.

Also, there is a per-page option in the SEO section to disable the canonical links there.

Answer (score 0):

go to web.xml and delete language mapping url after that start the server.

url--tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF